# Need to create animation on clicking any option in MCQ

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

i need to create a MCQ question with 4 options. On clicking any option i need proper correct mark with some color animation over it. how to do this animation part in appcelerator Titanium. Share link to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Animations are handled by the view object in Appcelerator. So, for example, if you put your answers in a label object, inside a view, then you can apply a animation. See the documentation and examples here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation